# TRSP from / to a two way road

Tags: pgrouting

In pgRouting 3.3 function pgr_trsp it was possible to specify the position on the start / end edge instead of just the start / end vertex. This seemed very useful since if the start / end edge is a two-way edge and the source / target was a point in the middle of the edge (as in most real life routing problems) there is no way of knowing from which vertex it's better to "enter" / "exit" the edge but comparing the cost of the possible routes. New 3.4 signature does not support specifying the position on the edge. Is there another alternative than to produce various routes?